# Jest test gives error: "Cannot read property of undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, unit-testing, jestjs

I'm writing a simple jest test but am receiving the following error:

```
[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'fields' of undefined"

[Vue warn]: Error in created hook: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'relationNumber' of undefined"
```

My jest test:

```
import { mount } from "@vue/test-utils";
import Step2 from "pathtoStep2.vue";

describe("Step2", () => {
  it("should enable button", async () => {
    const wrapper = mount(Step2);
    await wrapper
      .find("[data-testid='relationnumber-input']")
      .setValue("12341234123412");
    const button = wrapper.find("[data-testid='next-button']");
    expect(button.toBeEnabled());
  });
});
```

My field data object in step2.vue:

```
  data () {
    return {
      fields: {
        relationNumber: '',
      }
    }
  }
```

According to https://lmiller1990.github.io/vue-testing-handbook/simulating-user-input.html#creating-the-component
its not needed to initialise a data object? So what am I doing wrong?